# Import a class via template.php or other ways

Tags: 7, theming

I'm using Drupal 7 and have this structure:

```
<div id="node-11" class="node node-ortaklar-cv node-promoted node-teaser node-type-ortaklar_cv node-teaser-ortaklar_cv" typeof="sioc:Item foaf:Document" about="/tr/node/11">   
        <h2 datatype="" property="dc:title"><a href="/tr/node/11">Lorem Ipsum</a></h2>
    <div class="field field-name-field-cv-tr field-type-file field-label-hidden d_tr">
...
    </div>
```

I want add a class top of this structure. E.G.

```
**<div class="HEADER">**
   <div id="node-11" class="node node-ortaklar-cv node-promoted node-teaser node-type-ortaklar_cv node-teaser-ortaklar_cv" typeof="sioc:Item foaf:Document" about="/tr/node/11">   
            <h2 datatype="" property="dc:title"><a href="/tr/node/11">Lorem Ipsum</a></h2>
        <div class="field field-name-field-cv-tr field-type-file field-label-hidden d_tr">
    ...
        </div>
**</div>**
```

I don't use page.tpl.php files because using Views module. I put this code in template.php but don't working:

```
function mysite_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
if ($variables['style_name'] == 'node-ortaklar-cv') {
$variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'header';
}
```

}

Is is possible put a div in structure via template.php or some way? And how? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code needs to go in node.tpl.php, not page.tpl.php or template.php. Just follow these steps:

1. If you haven't already, copy the code from [node.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7) into a file with the same name inside your theme's folder.
2. Edit the node.tpl.php file and add your markup around the main node div
3. Flush Drupal's caches (or at least the theme reigstry)

Then your nodes will all be wrapped in the markup you need.

If you just need to do this for a specific content type (I'm going to guess at one called `image` here), your template file will need to be called node--image.tpl.php. You'll still need the original node.tpl.php file in your theme though, as node template overrides won't work without it.

Comment: thanks. Now, i must copy node.tpl.php files in my theme directory, after create node--mycontenttype-tpl.php files?

Comment: Yep that's the one. Make sure you call the file `node--mycontenttype.tpl.php` (notice the `.` instead of `-`) otherwise it won't work

Comment: Thank you, it's work. Well, how to embed field id in this class? E.g. <div id="myid">field_myfield</div> ?